# Пропорции 2 тулбаров и 2 фрагментов под ними

Tags: android, android-layout

Хотел сделать 2 тулбара и 2 фрагмента на одном экране.

Задал пропорции тулбарам (70/30) и фрагментам (69/31).

Между тулбарами и между фрагментами есть вертикальная разделительная полоска. Она не совпадает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что у меня нет возможности поставить в один слой тулбар с фрагментом и в другой слой, так как стоит сторонняя библиотека - боковой бар.

Он (расположен слева на картинке) занимает 72dp и "зажимает" фрагмент1, поэтому такие пропорции тулбарам (70/30) и фрагментам (69/31).

Так вот, хотелось бы узнать, **как можно программно выравнить**(или веса задать, или ширину в пикселях) **верхние пропорции к нижним?** Так как на разных экранах планшетов пропорции выглядят по разному и разделительная нижняя полоска не совпадает с верхней

Comment: Нужно объединить боковой бар и фрагмент 1 в одно view и тогда не будет никаких проблем. Даже если это сторонняя библиотека, вы же как-то отображаете его в дочернем view

Comment: @httpdispatch эта библиотека от MikePenz , а боковой бар - MiniDrawer. Работает как на планшете в gmail. При раскрытии бара, сдвигается полностью контейнер с 2 вложенными контейнерами (в которых и находятся 2 фрагмента). Как вы говорите, не получится в моём случае

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как на разных экранах альбомной ориентации пропорции ширины тулбаров и фрагментов разные, я решил взять ширину контейнера от фрагмента2 и установить её, как ширину тулбара2

```
container.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    toolbar2.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(container.getWidth(), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: container.getWidth(): " + container.getWidth());
                }
            });
```

Где `container` - это контейнер правого фрагмента(`fragment2`).

Делаю я это в `onCreate()` в классе `MainActivity`. Также я поставил условие, если устройство - планшет и в альбомной ориентации, то только тогда отображать 2й тулбар и устанавливать необходимую ширину.

Вдохновлялся [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0) (eng. S.O.)